How can I use Python to get a stock's Earnings date and time from the TraderWorkstation Api
I’m trying to get Earnings Date/Time info for AAPL using the Trader Workstation Api for Python.
I have subscribed to Wall Street Horizon data.
Using the following Python script:
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *
import os

port = 7496
class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        self.reqScannerParameters()

    def scannerParameters(self, xml):
        dir_path = "C:\\Temp\\Traders Academy"
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "scanner.xml")
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(xml)
    print("Scanner parameters has been stored.")

app = TestApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", port, 1001)
app.run()

I was able to store the XML, and in looking at it, I noticed:
<ScanType>
    <vendor>WSH</vendor>
    <displayName>Upcoming Earnings (WSH)</displayName>
    <scanCode>WSH_NEXT_EARNINGS</scanCode>
    <instruments>STK,STOCK.NA,STOCK.EU,STOCK.ME,STOCK.HK</instruments>
    <absoluteColumns>false</absoluteColumns>
    <Columns varName="columns">
        <Column>
            <colId>742</colId>
            <name>Upcoming Earnings</name>
            <display>true</display>
            <section>m</section>
            <displayType>DATA</displayType>
        </Column>
        <ColumnSetRef>
            <colId>0</colId>
            <name>BA</name>
            <display>false</display>
        <displayType>DATA</displayType>
    </ColumnSetRef>
    </Columns>
</ScanType>

I’m wondering if I can use this XML to create a filter to access the Earnings Date/Time info.
If so, how would I do this in Python?
The web manual pages for the Trader Workstation API are now deprecated. The code to access Wall Street Horizons data no longer works.  They say: "Go to Traders Acadamy" but there are no Api manual pages.  Very frustrating.
Charles

Please fix the indentation. It looks like part of def scannerParameters is not indented correctly.

Well, this has been quite a saga.  The following is a sample Python script that I found on the Wall Street Horizons website:
from ib_insync import *

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1234)

# Get the conId of an instrument (IBM in this case):
ibm = Stock('IBM', 'SMART', 'USD')
ib.qualifyContracts(ibm)
print(ibm.conId)  # is 8314

# Get the list of available filters and event types:
meta = ib.getWshMetaData()
#print(meta)

# For IBM (with conId=8314) query the:
#   - Earnings Dates (wshe_ed)
data = WshEventData(
    filter = '''{
      "country": "All",
      "watchlist": ["8314"],
      "limit_region": 10,
      "limit": 10,
      "wshe_ed": "true"
    }''')

earnings_data = ib.getWshEventData(data)

search_string = "wshe_earnings_date_status\":\"CONFIRMED\",\"fiscal_year\":\"2024\""
if search_string in earnings_data:
    start_index = earnings_data.index(search_string) + len(search_string)
    new_string = earnings_data[start_index:]
    search_string = "earnings_date\":\""
    if search_string in new_string:
        start_index = new_string.index(search_string) + len(search_string)
        new_string = new_string[start_index:]
        earnings_date = new_string[:8]
        print(f"earnings_date: {earnings_date}")
        search_string = "time_of_day\":\""
        if search_string in new_string:
            start_index = new_string.index(search_string) + len(search_string)
            new_string = new_string[start_index:]
            time_of_day = new_string.split(",", 1)[0]
            time_of_day = time_of_day[:-1]
            print(f"  time_of_day: {time_of_day}")
    else:
        print("earnings_date not found.")

It gives the following output:

It took several days before I found that Wall Street Horizons and Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation were not properly set up.  I previous subscribed to WSH data, but that was not enough.  I had to subscribe to a second WSH data subscription.  Here is what that looks like:

When I first tried the connection, I got a very long text string.  On further analysis, I noticed that the string was not XML or JSON code.  It is raw seething unstructured text.  I had to add code to brute force parse the text to get an earnings date and time for IBM.  How embarrassing. Someone needs to drag these two companies into the 21st Century.
